# Kinect Gesture tracking

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm developing an app (C#, Kinect SDK 1.8, sensor v1) which translates gestures tracked by Kinect and I want to use those gestures to say when x = ... y = ...

I can do this fairly easily with if statements but this is not really scalable and I'm sure there is a better approach but being new to C# and Kinect I'm not aware of it. It could be a way to read when hands move into certain zones in the screen or recognising hands relative to other parts of the body.
If anyone could help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend kinect to a c# beginner. Watch some MVA videos and you'll end up answering your own question.

Comment: Like ardaozakal said, your question isn't really a Kinect question, but an architecture one. Yes, there are better ways: you have to sit down and design an architecture for that. There are many tools available: inheritance, polymorphism, controls, etc. I believe that the Kinect SDK provides some samples containing controls that help you detect when hands are in certain zones of the screen: you can start there.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm looking at controls and hand cursor mapping etc. I'll repost how it goes.